# Footnote complete citation, plus ibid, op, cit., etc (in ConTeXt)

Tags: citing, context, context-mkiv

I need my citations to be in a footnote. I tried `\footnote{\cite[alternative=data][bib_key]}` but this can’t help me with *ibid.* or Author, *op. cit.* when required. Searching a little, I found something in the mailing list [1](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2010/046359.html), but I can’t make it work (I’m just a user, little to no coding skills).

Also, a couple of (maybe separate?) questions.

- Is there citation styles other than APA, AMS or APS? The Chicago style would be ideal for me (maybe there’s a module that defines it?)
- The APA style is mostly functional to me, but is there an (easy) way to change the year from between parentheses after the author to the end of the line after a comma?
- Is there a way to get a dash instead of repeating an author’s name in the bibliography (`\placepublications`)?

I am aware that bibliography is not the strength of ConTeXt, but I have been searching and, due to my lack of knowledge, everything just keep getting more confusing. I will appreciate any help I can get. Thank you.

Comment: Please also post on the context mailing list. The bibliography system has been revamped recently. Even if this is not possible currently, you will at least bring the problem to the attention of the developers.

Answer (score 2):

You could do most of this by using [pandoc](http://pandoc.org) to generate the tex file and then processing the tex file with ConTeXt. Specifically, you can definitely get citations in footnotes and em-dashes for repeated authors. Ibid, etc. are almost certainly possible as well. I don't know about the APA style modifications.

Pandoc uses [CSL](http://citationstyles.org) to format citations. Support for the Chicago styles is very good.

Of course, this means both learning pandoc and finding the right CSL files. So to give you a sense of whether it would be worth it for you to do those things, I will sketch what your documents would look like.

First, pandoc does not *read* context, so you will have to convert your source document to something it does read, like markdown.

Once you have your source file in a format pandoc reads, you would enter your citation key in your text, e.g. [@author:2015, 297–303]. When you call pandoc, you tell it what bibliographic style you want it to use, e.g.

```
pandoc -f markdown --bibliography=YourBibliographyFile.bib --csl=chicago-fullnote-bibliography-no-ibid.csl -t context -o OutputFile.tex InputFile.tex
```

If you are using a bibliographic style that calls for footnotes, pandoc will put the reference in a foonote. So, for example, if you were using the Chicago fullnote style, pandoc would put this in OutputFile.tex: \footnote{Author, {\em Title}, (X-place: X University Press), 297-303.}

If the style calls for Ibid or whatever, pandoc will insert those at the right places.

If you are using a bibliographic style that calls for in-text citations, like an author-date style, pandoc will put something like this in OutputFile.tex: (Author, 2015).

If your style calls for a bibliography, pandoc will produce one using the style's rules. For Chicago styles, three em dashes are put in place of a repeated author's name.

You can then run OutputFile.tex through ConTeXt.

Comment: It doesn’t recognize `context` as a valid input format: it responds `Unknown reader: context`. It is Pandoc 1.13.2 (most recent) in Windows. I changed the `-f` parameter to `latex` just to see what happen: it converted `[@kant_proleg, 99]` to `{[}@kant\low{p}roleg,
99{]}` without processing the bibliography. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: No, you're right: pandoc doesn't read context. I should have checked. One thing you could do is convert your source document to markdown. If you have undemanding formatting like italics, headers, and so on, it wouldn't be difficult. Then use -f markdown. One more thing: you need to install the Chicago CSL files yourself. Pandoc only has the Chicago author-date style by default.

Comment: It worked from markdown. I was actually thinking in use markdown + Pandoc to have a beautiful pdf-printed version, and an easy ePub, rtf… Unfortunately, most of my documents use “logical” definitions instead of “stylistic” ones (like, if I want to make an ironic comment, instead of using “” or italics, I define a command `\ironic` and there I make the `“#1”` or `{\em #1}` or change the font face, color or whatever. @Aditya has an interesting post in her blog https://randomdeterminism.wordpress.com/2012/06/01/how-i-stopped-worring-and-started-using-markdown-like-tex/ I might try that. Thanks!

Comment: That is pretty much what I do and I'm quite happy with it. Good luck!